# What all operators can be defined inside a struct in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

I actually cannot understand 3rd,4th line in the following code in C++ :

```
struct POINT {
      int x,y;
      POINT(int x = 0, int y = 0) : x(x), y(y) {}
      bool operator ==(POINT& a) {return a.x==x && a.y==y;}
};
```

Other examples/explanations are also welcome apart from this code snippet :)

Comment: Read a book and/or Google

Comment: The keywords you're looking for are "operator overloading"

Comment: @Eric : Thanks :) ! that was helpful but i still can't figure out what the last 2 lines mean !

Comment: 2nd last line means to initialize x,y to zero for each instance created while last line allows us to compare two structs(points here) directly with '==' . Ex- we have two variables A,B with above point structure. As such we can't compare if (A==B) ... but last line allows us to do so ,hope it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`structure` is nothing but a class with all its data members and functions defined in `public` scope. So you can implement any operators which is valid for a `class`.

If your question is on operator overloading, all overloaded operators can be defined  for a `class` is valid for a `structure`.

You can refer this [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) question and answer to understand more on operator overloading

```
POINT(int x = 0, int y = 0) : x(x), y(y) {} //(3rd line)
bool operator ==(POINT& a) {return a.x==x && a.y==y;}//(4th line)
```

3rd line is a `constructor`, and 4th line is an operator overloading function for operator `==`.

`POINT p1(2,3); // 3rd line will get called and update x=2 and y=3`

```
POINT p2; // 3rd line will get called and consider x=0 and y=0 
          //since function definitiion is defaulted with value x=0 and y=0;
if(p2==p1) {....}
  // 4th line will get called and compare P1 and P2
```

Comment: Thanks & can you explain what those last two lines means please :) ?

Comment: @ZooOoz I included a link for your reference in answer to answer your question

Comment: Your link definitely helps but the type of statements used in last two lines in above given code , i cannot find it in the link you provided ?

Comment: @ZooOoz I edited answer to answer your question in comment